# how to join 3 tables using laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel

**[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZqIN.png)**

**Code:**

```
function viewPDF()
{
    $reports = Report::join('president_report', 'reports.id', '=', 'president_report.report_id')
        ->join('president_report', 'presidents.id', '=', 'president_report.president_id')->
        select('reports.*')->where('president_report.report_id')
        ->filter()->latest()->get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.test1', ['reports' => $reports]);
    return $pdf->stream('reports.pdf');
}
```

**Error:**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique
>   table/alias: 'president_report' (SQL: select * from `reports` inner
>   join `president_report` on `reports`.`id` =
>   `president_report`.`report_id` inner join `president_report` on
>   `presidents`.`id` = `president_report`.`president_id` where
>   `president_report`.`report_id` is null order by `created_at` desc)

Answer (score 0):

Use separate aliases for the two joins with the `president_reports` table:

```
function viewPDF() {
    $reports = Report::join('president_report pr1', 'reports.id', '=', 'pr1.report_id')
        ->join('president_report pr2', 'presidents.id', '=', 'pr2.president_id')->
    select('reports.*')->where('pr1.report_id')
        ->filter()->latest()->get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.test1', ['reports' => $reports]);
    return $pdf->stream('reports.pdf');
}
```

Note that the second join looks suspicious to me, because I don't see where the `presidents` table is getting included in the join query.  But the general solution to use problem is to alias `president_report` differently for the two joins.